# How to change css content dynamically in EXtJS

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have one css in my resource folder and I want to change/add few of the values in css as per my condition but I am not getting idea how to get that.

Example code is here

```
triggers: {
        clear: {
            cls: 'Clear-Value',
            hidden:true,
            handler: function(){
                //some code
            }
        }
    },
```

my css of clear-value is

```
.Clear-Value:before {
    background-color:white !important;  }
```

Now I want put some clss in some condition. Like add padding aor some thing else.

I am trying like this

```
beforerender: function (cmp, eOpts) {
        debugger;
        var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
        if(isFirefox){
            this.triggers.clear.cls // Here I am getting Clear-Value
        }
    },
```

I am getting my cls but need some help to edit css. Can anybody help to fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: Would it not be better to have the CSS you want to add in a separate CSS class / selector hierarchy and add these classes to your trigger rather than editing the CSS itself? I.e. add '.firefox-trigger-padding-fix' to your CSS and then let your trigger cls be 'Clear-Value firefox-trigger-padding-fix'?

Comment: `.firefox-trigger-padding-fix` is only will work for fierfoex is it. how my css will be look like.

Comment: It depends exactly what you want to do. I'm sure there are CSS tags that are explicit to firefox browsers, but I don't have them to hand. If you go that route then you won't need to edit the CSS class in Ext at all and it will be all CSS driven. Adding the class in JS lets you do other checks as well. The example I gave would give the trigger both classes `.Clear-Value` and `.firefox-trigger-padding-fix`, so you can apply CSS to it using either a simple `.firefox-trigger-padding-fix {...}` selector or a selector that requires both (`.firefox-trigger-padding-fix .Clear-Value {...}`)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new CSS class and add style you require for Firefox in it. Add this class to components classlist only if browser is Firefox.

try this...

```
beforerender: function (cmp, eOpts) {
        var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1;
        if(isFirefox){
            cmp.addCls('firefox-fix');
        }
},

.firefox-fix { padding-top :7px !important; }
```

Add your CSS for Firefox in `firefox-fix` CSS class.
I hope this helps.

Comment: How about `Ext.isGecko`?